# url() 指定のある css を gulp で1つにまとめるには？

Tags: gulp

例えば以下のように `a/css/a.css`, `b/css/b.css` があったとき、これらをまとめて `css/x.css` を作りたいとします。

```
a/css/a.css -- url(../image/A.png) の参照あり
a/image/A.png
b/css/b.css -- url(../image/A.png) の参照あり
b/image/A.png
```

gulp-concat で単純に連結すると、 url() の参照先が無効になります。gulp でまとめた時に url() の参照を有効に保つにはどうしたらよいでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

まさにそのような処理を行うのに特化したgulpプラグイン、[gulp-css-rebase-urls](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-css-rebase-urls)があります。いかがですか？

(試したわけではないので求める動作を満たさなかったらすみません......)